# Resetting height: auto on img element

Tags: html, css, image

I have an `img` element whose width and height are explicitly specified:

```
<img src="http://example.com/something.jpg" width="100" height="200" />
```

There's an external stylesheet that sets `height: auto` on all images, which overrides my pre-computed width and height and causes the image to be zero-height until the image header is read. This breaks my layout momentarily.

Is there any way to override `height: auto` on an `img` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline styling to the image, for example:

```
<img src="" style="height:200px" />
```

that you will remove once your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<img src="http://example.com/something.jpg" style="height: 200px!important;" width="100" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline styles to override styles on css stylesheets. You can find a good article [here](http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence)